# Swift 2.0 - pass a tuple struct to function

Tags: swift, struct, tuples, nserror

I want to pass a struct of tuples to a function, and I got the error of unknown tuple fields:

```
import UIKit

struct MyClassConstants {
    static let DOMAIN = "MyClassDomain"

    struct Error {
        static let ERROR1 = (code: -1, description: "Error1 description")
        static let ERROR2 = (code: -2, description: "Error2 description")
    }
}

extension NSError {
    public class func MyClassError(error: MyClassConstants.Error) -> NSError {
        return NSError(domain: MyClassConstants.DOMAIN, code: error.code, userInfo: ["description": error.description]) // error here!!
    }
}

class MyClass: NSObject {
    // some properties
    func doSomething() {
       let error = NSError.MyClassError(MyClassConstants.Error.Error1)
       // ...
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Value of type "MyClassConstants.Error" has no member 'code'.
```

I think the reason of the error in `MyClassError` is I have not casted `error` parameter to a tuple? How can I do that? Or any other reasons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually took me a while to figure out where the error is.

It's so easy to miss it.

The error occurs because the parameter - `error` is an instance of `MyClassConstants.Error`. Using this instance, you can only access *instance* methods or properties of that type. However, your `MyClassConstants.Error` has no instance properties! It contains only static properties!

You need to know that `ERROR1` and `ERROR2` are not of type `MyClassConstants.Error`. They are of type `(code: Int, description: String)`!

So yeah...

The second error that you get is at:

```
let error = NSError.MyClassError(MyClassConstants.Error.Error1)
```

Because `ERROR1` is not of type `MyClassConstants.Error`, it cannot be passed into the method.

How to fix this:

Well, here's the self-explanatory code:

```
// Change MyClassError method to this:
public class func MyClassError(error: (code: Int, description: String)) -> NSError {
    return NSError(domain: MyClassConstants.DOMAIN, code: error.code, userInfo: ["description": error.description]) // error here!!
}
```